# Get the position of a UIImageView

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview, uiimage

I have an existing UIImageView with variable X and Y coordinates. The picture should move according to the current position difference but I don't know how I get the current position.

```
picture = UIImageView(frame: CGRectMake(corx, cory, 25, 25))
```

I hope you can help me out.

Comment: If you find any of the answers useful you should accept one of them...that's the etiquette :)

Comment: Haven't had time time yet to try the answers out. If I find a helpful answer im going to accept them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get coordinates of a view in two different ways.

`picture.bounds` - The bounds rectangle, which describes the view’s location and size in its own coordinate system.

`picture.frame` - The frame rectangle, which describes the view’s location and size in its superview’s coordinate system.

in both cases the size component should be the same.

In the code below origin will be the point with your original coordinates (corx,cory).

```
CGPoint origin = picture.frame.origin
```

You probably want to use picture.frame.origin to animate your view. You can always say `picture.frame = <new frame>` once you have created your instance and adjust this new frame's origin.

Example

```
CGRect r = picture.frame;
r.origin.x += 10;
r.origin.y += 10;
picture.frame = r;
```

This will not be a smooth animation though - you can animate frame property using CoreAnimation for a smooth transition.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 2):

Just get the frame of the picture:

```
picture.frame.origin.x
picture.frame.origin.y
```

Comment: Why change from your original answer: picture.frame.origin.x, etc... That seemed more clear/correct...

Comment: Good point.  I was re-reading the question and thought he meant a general view. But you're right -- picture makes more sense

Answer (score 0):

Use the x and y coordinates from the frame of the view you want to base it off of. Anything inheriting from UIView will have a frame associated with it.

```
var picture = UIImageView(frame: CGRectMake(view.frame.origin.x, view.frame.origin.y, 25, 25))
```